# How to add negative timestamps to TeeChart X axis with C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, teechart

I have data with relative timestamp (as [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)). Example:

```
RelativeTimestamp (hh:mm) | Data1 | Data2
-00:03                      2.2     1.3
-00:01                      2.5     1.5
 00:00                      2.4     1.6
 00:02                      2.7     1.7
 00:08                      2.1     1.9
```

I want to make a TeeChart with C# that draws these series of data. However when I try

```
series.Add(row["RelativeTimestamp"], row["Data1"]);
```

It complains that I cannot use TimeStamp on horizontal axis. So I also tried converting it to [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) with

```
DateTime RelativeTimestamp_DT = row["RelativeTimestamp"] + (new DateTime(1970,1,1));
```

but, of course, this makes the series of timestamps to become 23:57, -23:59 etc instead of anything negative.

So, how can I make negative timestamp labels on X axis?

We can assume that relative timestamp is no larger than 24 hours positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `Series.Add(DateTime X, double Y, string Label)`, which existence I didn't notice at first. This is nice because I can put the data to right position on X axis, but give it a custom label, even when timestamps are unequally distributed:

```
foreach (DataRow in data.Rows) {
    DateTime RelativeTimestamp_DT = DateTime.MinValue + row["RelativeTimestamp"];

    string label = row["RelativeTimestamp"].ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    if (row["RelativeTimestamp"] < new TimeSpan(0)) {
        label = "-" + label;
    }

    series.Add(row["RelativeTimestamp"], row["Data1"], label);
    series.Add(row["RelativeTimestamp"], row["Data2"], label);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I can think of is using text labels based on a TimeSpan, for example:

```
  var line1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line(tChart1.Chart);
  var y = new Random();

  for (int i = -20; i < 20; i++)
  {
    var referenceTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(i);
    var timeSpan = referenceTime - currentTime;

    var label = timeSpan.ToString(@"h\h\:m\m");
    label = (currentTime < referenceTime) ? "-" + label : label;

    line1.Add(y.Next(), label);
  }

  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
```

Which produces this chart:

[image]

Comment: The answer is nice, but the this looks correct only if time stamps are regular. Like in your code they are 25h (?) separate from each others. Trend is not correct e.g. if there is longer or shorter breaks.

Comment: @Travenin thanks. Time stamps are at 1 hour intervals. I made it that way to get a simple automatic self contained example. Labels are only displayed every second hour to avoid overlapping.